# Merging a "Form_Closing" method with the form's "Dispose" method

Tags: c#, forms, dispose

I have a custom control in my MDI parent that acts as a "checklist" for any open forms. Whenever a form is opened, it calls an `AddToOpenForms` method, which adds the form name to this list. Then, when the form is closed, it calls a `RemoveFromOpenForms` method, which then removes it from the list.

```
Controller
{
    OpenNewForm()
    {
        Form f = new Form();
        f.Show();
        AddToOpenForms(f);
    }

    CloseForm(Form f)
    {
        RemoveFromOpenForms(f);
    }
}

Form1
{
     Form1(Controller c)
     {
         InitializeComponent();
     }

     private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        c.CloseForm(this);
    }
}
```

However, shortcuts have been added to instead of closing the form via the usual `Form_Closing` method, they are instead called in a `using` method. This instead skips over the `Form_Closing` method, and jumps straight to the `Dispose` method. Therefore, the Form isn't closed, so the `RemoveFromOpenForms` is not called, and then item remains in the list.

What I have done in the meantime, is add the call for `RemoveFromOpenForms` to the `Dispose` method, but I'm not sure if this is the proper solution.

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing && (components != null))
    {
        this.c.CloseForm(this);
        components.Dispose();
    }
    base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

Comment: I'm about to go offline, so won't be able to debate this, but why not question a deeper assumption: why maintain the list of open forms?  Why not just use the MdiParent form's MdiChildren property?  It seems to track what you need on its own without all the extra overhead.

Comment: @ScottMermelstein I might be missing something in your argument, but the list is merely a User tool. It allows the user to see which windows they have open, bring focus to them, or close them as they see fit (using a context menu). Are you suggesting that the current method of adding these "open" forms is already part of the MdiChildren property?

Comment: Yes, I think that's just what I'm suggesting.  What use is a multiple document interface that doesn't track the documents for you?  In fact, even outside of MDI, any winforms application will keep track of the windows that are open using `Application.OpenForms`.  So yes, I'm suggesting that if you're going to have a windows pane, you drive it off of the data that's already maintained.  You shouldn't need any OpenForms collection of your own.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. So I should develop the method to update, using event listeners on this collection instead?

Comment: If your control only displays on user demand (i.e. a menu or context menu), just fill your view from an existing open form list anytime it's displayed.  If it's always visible, you're not really in any better shape than when you started - you'll want to refresh the control on any Open, Close or Dispose.  I'm not aware of being able to attach an event listener to `Application.OpenForms`, but it's entirely possible there's a way to do it.  Your other option, if you don't want to insert all these refresh calls into Open Close and Dispose is to have the control refresh on a timer.